# getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic.descriptor.BeanUpdateListener after applying weblogic 10.3.6 patch

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, weblogic-10.x

getting error while applying patch on web logic 10.3.6 version .

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   weblogic.descriptor.BeanUpdateListener

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.descriptor.BeanUpdateListener

this is the error in log file after applying patch . you need to give the execute permission at /prod/applc/bea1036/wlserver/server/lib directory to newly created .jar files.

Comment: change permission to 755 atleast.